# Method is not getting passed down while doing Inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function constructor defined this way:

```
var Person = function (name, yearOfBirth, job) {
            this.name = name;
            this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
            this.job = job;
        }
        Person.prototype.calculateAge = function () {
            console.log(2016 - this.yearOfBirth);
        };
```

Now I also have another function constructor called Teacher which I've defined this way:

```
var Teacher = function (name, yearOfBirth, subject) {
            Person.call(this, name, yearOfBirth, "teacher");
            this.subject = subject;
        }
```

Now I create a new object called roySir this way:

```
var roySir = new Teacher("Roy", 1960, "English");
```

However when I try to do
roySir.calculateAge() I get an error saying that

> "roySir.calculateAge is not a function"

How come the calculateAge function is not inherited here?

[image]

Another question I have is when I check:

```
roySir.hasOwnProperty("name") // true
```

Why is this true here?  Isn't name a property of the parent class rather than an own property?

[image]

Comment: are you in a JS environment that supports the new ES6 `class` - much easier to do

Comment: no.. just following a tutorial.. but it doesn't go in to a lot of detail as to why this works the way it does..

Comment: but it doesn't work? so the tutorial is flawed

Comment: no.. it works in the tutorial.. cuz they didn't have the prototype method.. i just added it myself as a learning exercise..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ensure that `Teacher`'s prototype inherits from `Person`'s prototype. Simply `call`ing `Person` with a `Teacher` won't let `Teacher` inherit from `Person`'s prototype methods:

```js
var Person = function(name, yearOfBirth, job) {
  this.name = name;
  this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
  this.job = job;
}
Person.prototype.calculateAge = function() {
  console.log(2016 - this.yearOfBirth);
};
var Teacher = function(name, yearOfBirth, subject) {
  Person.call(this, name, yearOfBirth, "teacher");
  this.subject = subject;
}
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
var roySir = new Teacher("Roy", 1960, "English");
roySir.calculateAge();
```

You need the `Object.create` rather than `Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype` there so that mutations to `Teacher.prototype` won't undesirably change `Person`s that aren't `Teacher`s - for example, if you gave `Teacher.prototype` a `teachesClass` method, you would want only `Teacher`s to have access to that, but you wouldn't want a generic `Person` to have that method.

Alternatively, use ES6 and `extends`, which is more readable:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, yearOfBirth, job) {
    this.name = name;
    this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
    this.job = job;
  }
  calculateAge() {
    console.log(2016 - this.yearOfBirth);
  }
}
class Teacher extends Person {
  constructor(name, yearOfBirth, subject) {
    super(...[name, yearOfBirth, subject, 'teacher']);
  }
}
var roySir = new Teacher("Roy", 1960, "English");
roySir.calculateAge();
```

As for the `name` property, it's assigned to the object itself with `this.name = name;` - when a constructor is called, like with `Person.call(this, ...)`, the `this` in the other constructor still refers directly to the object being created in the calling code - that's what `call` does, the first argument passed to it will be a direct reference to the `this` used in the other function.

The prototype chain looks like:

```
roySir { name, yearOfBirth, job }
above inherits from Teacher.prototype (empty)
above inherits from Person.prototype { calculateAge }
```

Comment: why did you do Teacher.protoype = Object.create(Person.prototype).. can I just say Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype; ?.. are they same thing?

Comment: See edit - if you do that, mutations to `Teacher.prototype` will undesirably change `Person.prototype` as well - you won't be using inheritance, you'll just be overwriting the other prototype object.

Comment: Yes I was just reading the edit. Thank you so much for making that clear.  could you also please answer my other question about hasOwnProperty... ? :)